# Restart Delayed_Job after server shutdown or crash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I use capistrano to start delayed_job automatically whenever I deploy an update, but how do I make it restart automatically after a server shutdown or crash?

Comment: It depends on your system, on your architecture, if you have some VM, your user, ....

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm if I have VM?  it's on ubuntu 14.10

Comment: So search on Google how to run a custom service into `init.d`. You can have the correct commandline when your deploy your application (look for a line with `delayed_job`).